# Chromium not playing mp3?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, mp3, chromium

For some reason, the same mp3 files :

- [http > my.mp3](http://prison-lavage.codio.io/audio/cmn/syllabs/cmn-hao3.mp3)
- [https> same.mp3](https://prison-lavage.codio.io/audio/cmn/syllabs/cmn-hao3.mp3)

**plays on Firefox**, and **doesn't play on Chromium Version 37.0.2062.94** Ubuntu 14.04 (290621) (64-bit). Using the Code inspector, I see no feedbacks in the console.

**What is going wrong ? How to make it work ?**

Comment: May mp3 not been supported by default ? http://www.chromium.org/audio-video

Comment: Hey guys, this Q/A has +2500 views but just few up votes. If you find it useful thanks to +1, it's always appreciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a not completely free format, Mp3 is not supported by Chromium out of the box. See http://www.chromium.org/audio-video

**Solutions:**

- Ubuntu:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree
  ```
- Windows: see  [How do I add MP3, MP4 and H.264 support to Chromium on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/655605/)

Comment: The proposed solution for Ubuntu gives me the error "Unable to locate package chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-nonfree".